# NSLog invalid in Xcode

Tags: ios, nslog

I am confused for a long time. In my Project, the nslog is invalid,like:

```
 NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",nil];

NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

In the console there is no result. In the debugger, I can see the `arr` in the local, and when I select:"Print Description to Console", it shows in the console like:

```
Printing description of arr:
(gdb)
```

In My Project I use some lib built in C&C++, and I add them as frame work. I find the NSlog always becomes invalid after I create a pthread and do sth using the lib.
I've no idea about it and can any give tips?

thanks!

Comment: So `NSLog` works in the main thread but not in other threads? Or does it fail everywhere?

Comment: @Deepak，Before I use the lib the <code>NSLog</code> works well in both main and secondary threads. When I create a pthread using the lib, NSLog becomes in valid everywhere. The most important is in debugger I can see the variable but it can't be print to console.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `NSLog()` with `fprintf()` to `stderr`?

Comment: @Bavarious, it failed either.My code:'code'fprintf(stderr, "c"); (right?).

Comment: That should’ve worked. I’m not sure what’s the cause of the problem. It could be the case that the library does something evil with `stderr`, preventing your code from using it for output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to clean(shift+command+k) your project. 
It works for me.

Answer (score -3):

Try this way

```
for(int i=0; i<[arr length]; ++i)
     NSLog(@"%@",arr[i]);
```

Comment: Normally, an array can be displayed like the line of code the OP described. Perhaps the nil-part in @scorpiozj line confuses the NSLog?

Comment: @Joetjah,I don't think so. as %@ represents object and I try that in another project and it works.

Comment: Your code must work, I look for examples and everything is correct

Comment: Just so not everybody has to hit that link, props for ViTo: This works for NSArrays (as well as NSDictionaries, NSSets, etc). If you have a plain C array, you'll have to write a loop to print each element. (This also assumes you know the size of the array.)

The %@ format specifier, more specifically, uses the output of the object's "description" method. Most Foundation and AppKit classes implement this method, so you can use it to print all kinds of objects and get meaningful output. (For example, -[NSArray description] returns an NSString composed of the descriptions of all its elements.)

Comment: There’s no `-[NSArray length]`; it’s not possible to access `NSArray` elements via `[]`; there’s no reason why the answer code (if it were correct) would work if the code in the question doesn’t.

Comment: for(int i=0; i<[arr length]; ++i)
     NSLog(@"%@",arr[i]); 
 @Bavarious you want to say that this code is incorrect ?

Comment: @Bavarious but I write code in this way and it works. Maybe it was for NSMutableArray